# errors when opening files (browse)

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I have the code to read data (browse) using OpenFileDialog, which I will 
read is the image and I will enter into the database, therefore I do
convert to a byte data type, but when I do not browse and immediately press the save button, 
will out the error dialog, anyone can help me solve this ..
how that error could be I replace with a messagebox..

```
byte[] ReadFile(string sPath)
{
    //Initialize byte array with a null value initially.
    byte[] data = null;

    //Use FileInfo object to get file size.
    FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(sPath);
    long numBytes = fInfo.Length;

    //Open FileStream to read file
    FileStream fStream = new FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    //Use BinaryReader to read file stream into byte array.
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);

    //When you use BinaryReader, you need to supply number of bytes to read from file.
    //In this case we want to read entire file. So supplying total number of bytes.
    data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);

    return data;
}

private void btnImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.Filter = "JPG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
    DialogResult dlgRes = dlg.ShowDialog();
    if (dlgRes != DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        pctImage.ImageLocation = dlg.FileName;
        txtImage.Text = dlg.FileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: When entering code that spans multiple lines, you don't use the backtick.  You need to indent each line by four spaces.

Comment: Take note that if you are only reading into a byte array, you don't need a `BinaryReader`.  You can just use the [`FileStream.Read(byte[] array, int start, int count)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) method.

Comment: you don't need the stream either - just use `data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);`

Comment: Your code doesn't show us where and when `ReadFile` is being called.

Comment: At which codeline does the exception occur?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's guess from what you've posted, but you might want to look at testing for there being a suitable file to save selected.
Browse operation suggests they've switched floders and chose one.
On just opening the dialog, if they don't click on a file (given there is one), digging out the image is going to be an invalid operation.